# GWT TableCellElement is not showing background images

Tags: gwt

I am using gwt for showing an image inside a table cell, its a dynamic image so I don't need to hard code it but its not showing the actuall image inside it. Here is my code..

My UiBinder is somthing like:

```
    <table>
       <tr><td ui:field="tableCellElement"/></tr>
    </table>
```

My presenter is accessing the element in a  method :

```
    void someMethod(Image patterImage) {
        tableCellElement.setBackgroundImage("url('"+patternImage.getUrl()+"')");
        // and I have tried this without using url as well but it doesn't work
        // DOM.setstyleattribute also doesn't work...
    }
```

The code executes successfully but it doesn't show the image, I am using IE9 at the moment but I have tried it on IE8 and 7 as well.

I know it could be solved with the css but here our image is dynamic so if we have 100 images I can't define 100 css for each image..

I really appreciate if someone can sort that out for me.

Comment: Post your owner class for the UI Binder template. I used `com.google.gwt.dom.client.TableCellElement` class for the UiField tableCellElement. But I find that `TableCellElement` does not define `setBackgroundImage`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically ok. The reason you don't see the image is probably just that the default size of the td is 0.

Background images don't influence the size of the element, so you need to set it manually. If the size of all images is the same, you can set it once in UiBinder:

```xml
<ui:style>
  .myTableCell {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
</ui:style>

...

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="{style.myTableCell}" ui:field="tableCellElement"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Otherwise, set it programmatically:

```java
Style style = tableCellElement.getStyle();

style.setBackgroundImage("url('"+patternImage.getUrl()+"')");
style.setWidth(patternImage.getWidth(), Unit.PX);
style.setHeight(patternImage.getHeight(), Unit.PX);
```